# Put all nodes in the path from root to target node in a stack

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I need to push all the nodes up to my target node into a stack, if its in path from root node to target node. e.g my tree is

```
          20
       8     22
    4     12
 2     1
```

My root node is 20 and my target node is 4. So, the stack should contain 20,8 and 4. I try to come up with algorithm but all of them fail. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with following solution. It will print the correct solution but the only problem with it is that it will traverse the entire tree.

```
vector<int> store;

void createStore(node* root,node* target){   if(root==NULL)
                    return;
            else{
                    store.push_back(root);
                    createStore(root->left,target);
                    createStore(root->right,target);
            }
            if(store[store.size()-1]==target)
                    return;
            else{
                    cout<<store[store.size()-1]->data<<endl;
                    store.pop_back();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion here. Psuedo-code is as follows:

```
bool found_target( node *root )
{
   if ( root->val == target || found_target( root->left ) || found_target( root->left ) )
   {
      push( root, stack);
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First find the target node. Then traverse the pointers to parent nodes until you reach the root. As you traverse each link, push a node's value onto the stack.

Comment: No need to find the target node separately. Doing any tree traversal would work fine. Also, how do you `traverse the pointers to parent nodes until you reach the root`? You can't assume that the nodes have parent pointers.